# message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value[message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value]

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, encryption, cryptography

Please look below code. I'm trying to signed the json data using chilkat library. Its always throwing me error in portal that message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value.

```
        Chilkat.Crypt2 crypt = new Chilkat.Crypt2();
        //crypt.VerboseLogging = true;
        Chilkat.Cert cert = new Chilkat.Cert();
        cert.VerboseLogging = true;
        // Set the smart card PIN, which will be needed for signing.
        cert.SmartCardPin = "1121212";
        // There are many ways to load the certificate.  
        // This example was created for a customer using an ePass2003 USB token.
        // Assuming the USB token is the only source of a hardware-based private key..          
         cert.LoadFromSmartcard("");
        // Tell the crypt class to use this cert.
        crypt.SetSigningCert(cert);
        Chilkat.JsonObject cmsOptions = new Chilkat.JsonObject();
       // Setting "DigestData" causes OID 1.2.840.113549.1.7.5 (digestData) to be used.
        cmsOptions.UpdateBool("DigestData", true);
        cmsOptions.UpdateBool("OmitAlgorithmIdNull", true);           
        // Indicate that we are passing normal JSON and we want Chilkat do automatically
        // do the ITIDA JSON canonicalization:
        cmsOptions.UpdateBool("CanonicalizeITIDA", true);
         crypt.CmsOptions = cmsOptions.Emit();
    // The CadesEnabled property applies to all methods that create CMS/PKCS7signatures. 
        // To create a CAdES-BES signature, set this property equal to true. 
        crypt.CadesEnabled =true;
        crypt.HashAlgorithm = "sha256";
       Chilkat.JsonObject jsonSigningAttrs = new Chilkat.JsonObject();
        jsonSigningAttrs.UpdateInt("contentType", 1);
        jsonSigningAttrs.UpdateInt("signingTime", 1);
        jsonSigningAttrs.UpdateInt("messageDigest", 1);
        jsonSigningAttrs.UpdateInt("signingCertificateV2", 1);
        crypt.SigningAttributes = jsonSigningAttrs.Emit();
        crypt.IncludeCertChain = false;          
        // Create the CAdES-BES signature.    
        // Make sure we sign the utf-8 byte representation of the JSON string
        crypt.Charset = "utf-8";
        string strResultJsons = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
       System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\jsondata\pathaxtestsignin.json",strResultJsons);
        string signedjson = @"D:\jsondata\pathaxtestsignin.json";
        string signedjsovalue = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(signedjson);
        crypt.EncodingMode = "base64";          
        string sigBase64 = crypt.SignStringENC(signedjsovalue);
        return Ok(sigBase64);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess at the cause of the problem.  Here are my 2 best guesses:

1. System.IO.File.ReadAllText tries to discern the character encoding of the file it's reading.  Perhaps it incorrectly guessed ANSI and the non-usascii chars, each represented as multiple bytes, were interpreted as 2 ANSI chars per (would should be) a single utf-8 char.
2. Or perhaps.. the sigBase64 is correct and the ReadAllText correctly interpreted the file as utf-8, but your HTTP request sent using another charset (ANSI or utf-16?) when it should've sent utf-8.   You would need to examine the HTTP related code..

Comment: Thank you for your reponse. What about this cmsOptions.UpdateBool("DigestData", true) ? Do I need to set the value for DigestData or automatic ? Also please what is best way to read all my json value as single source instead of reading from files. So it can fit with your example.